# Google Maps in jquery UI Dialog Not Moving With Scroll (Chrome only)

Tags: jquery-ui, google-maps, google-chrome

I have a jQuery UI dialog that contains a google map. In Chrome when you move the scroll wheel on the mouse the map doesn't move down the page with the rest of the dialog and parts of the dialog start to disappear.

If I remove the div with google maps and scroll the mouse the dialog stays centered in the screen and the background just moves.

This doesn't happen in Firefox or IE.

Any ideas how I can debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It helps me, I've added it into my *Initialize* function:

```
var href = window.location.href;
    if (jQuery.browser.webkit && href.search("maps.google") > 0) {
    var childs = document.getElementById("map").childNodes;
    for (var i = 0, l = childs.length; i < l; i++) {
        childs[i].addEventListener("mousewheel", function () { return false; }, false);
    }
}
```

And I've removed =) *google.maps.InfoWindow*